# Spacing between checkbox and text?

Tags: css, woocommerce, woocommerce-checkout-fields

I'm having trouble figuring out how to add custom CSS to add spacing between a checkbox and text ( Ship to a different address?). Anytime I add margin or padding the whole element (checkbox + text) is moved. See picture attached?
Thanks for your help!

https://roynattivmd.com/checkout/

Checkbox and text:

[image: 1]

Comment: Can you re-create a small sample of the issue here with code so we can easily engage with it?

Comment: Yes, we need your current html and css code

Answer (score 1):

You could add some spacing by adding `margin-right: [value];` to the specific input. Since you are using [elementor](https://elementor.com/), you might do this via inline-styles.

```
<label for="myInput">
  <input id="myInput" type="checkbox" style="margin-right: .5rem;">
  Ship to a different address?
</label>
```

Or via an external stylesheet:

```css
#myInput {
  margin-right: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<label for="myInput">
  <input id="myInput" type="checkbox">
  Ship to a different address?
</label>
```

Comment: Since this is a Bootsrap website, adding `mr-1` as a class name doesn't require you to edit any code

Comment: You can edit my answer with your suggestion if you want.

Comment: Thanks, but I think this is not neccessary, I guess a comment is enough of a hint.

Comment: That's because I'm curious about it... Maybe my question is where have I to put that class.

Comment: Reviewed, accepted your changes. Thanks you. I misunderstood what you said.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code,To Spacing between checkbox and text?

```
    dd label input {
           margin-right:10px;
        }
    <dd id="rr-element">
           <label for="rr-1">
              <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="rr-1" name="rr[]">
              Value 1
           </label>
        </dd>
```

I hope this code will be useful.

Thank you.